# How do I update a custom date in C++?

Tags: c++, date

I created my own DateTime class. It accepts the current date/time, and it also accepts a custom date/time. The custom date/time is what I'm interested in.

If I set the date to 1/5/1953 with a time of 1:05:31 PM, and call updateTime(), I want the time to update based on the difference between when it was first created and how many milliseconds followed afterwards.

However, when I do this, it's always giving me today's date and time, which is not the desired result.

This is my current code.

```
if (m_isCustomDate)
{ 
    time_t currentRawTime; 

    // Get the current raw time
    time(&currentRawTime);

    // Get the time lapse  
    time_t time_diff = (time_t)difftime(currentRawTime, m_rawTime);

    // Increment the time difference to the old raw time
    m_rawTime += time_diff;

    // Update the tm structure
    localtime_s(&m_tm, &m_rawTime); 
}
```

Updated problem:
With a date of date to 1/5/1953 and with a time of 1:05:10 PM, and when I call getSecond(), it's not giving me the 10 as I expect, but it gives me the current second on my computer (4 in this case). Is localtime_s() not the right function to use in this case?

My getSecond() function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the current second between 0 and 60.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns the second.</returns>
int DateTime::getSecond()
{
    updateTime();

    return m_tm.tm_sec;
}
```

Updated specific question:
How can I get the time lapse between the original custom date (m_rawTime) and the time lapse since the app's start up, and then update the tm structure?

Edit:
This solution worked. Posting if anyone needs a working example:

```
    const DWORD curr_time = GetTickCount();
    DWORD time_diff = (curr_time - m_init_time) / 1000; 

    m_rawTime += time_diff;

    localtime_s(&m_tm, &m_rawTime); 
    m_init_time = curr_time;
```

Comment: Would love to see a minimal working example to play around.

Comment: Show your implementation of `getMinute()`

Comment: From my understanding, it's not how I'm calculating the time difference; it's why I'm still getting today's current date/time, etc. and not the custom date/time I give it.

Comment: ... with its updated seconds, etc. since the app's startup.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `m_rawTime` holds the 'custom' time, I noticed the following. With `time_t time_diff = (time_t)difftime(currentRawTime, m_rawTime);` you get the difference between the current time and `m_rawTime`. Then, with `m_rawTime += time_diff;` you make `m_rawTime` equal to the current time. I think, this is not what you want to do.

You say you want the time to "update based on the difference between when it was first created and how many milliseconds followed afterwards". So, you effectively want the difference between the time the object was last updated and the current time. To do that, initialize some counter (say, `this->init_time`) to the current time *in the constructor* and make each call to `updateTime` add the difference between the current time and `this->init_time` and make the latter equal to that current time:

```
void DateTime::updateTime() {
    const auto curr_time = get_time(); // this is not an actual function
    const auto diff = curr_time - this->init_time;

    m_rawTime += diff;
    // update the tm structure here...
    this->init_time = curr_time;
}
```

Now, if you want to work with milliseconds, microseconds or smaller time periods, you should use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, *but* `struct tm` [doesn't support](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/) time periods shorter than one second, so you can't actually make your custom time any more precise than that with it. In other words, if you stick to `struct tm`, you can only work with precision of one second, no more.

Comment: The problem sounds correct. What I'm interested in is updating the original custom date with its time lapse in seconds, minutes, etc.

Comment: @Phil, does `m_rawTime` represent the 'custom' time? If yes, you're indirectly setting it equal to the current time in your code.

Comment: Yes. That seems to be the case.

Comment: How can I get the time lapse between the original custom date (m_rawTime) and the time lapse since the app's start up, and then update the tm structure?

Comment: @Phil, I don't think you want the time lapse between the custom date and the moment of your program's startup. You don't want the difference between the custom date and the current time in general. You need the difference between the time of a `DateTime` object's _creation_ (or the moment of last update, to be precise) and the current time. Once you have that difference, add it to the custom time, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine. I'll post my solution above.